# text of li in center?

Tags: html, css

I got `ul` with `li` and i wanna make `li` smaller, I did it with `height:30px` but now text is not in middle of `li`:

[image]

How to fix it?

```css
  .properties_list .property_item
    {
        display:inline-block;
        font-size:15px;
    }
    .properties_list
    {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        height: 30px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .property_item
    {
        margin-right: 3px;
        height:30px;
    }
```

```html
 <ul class="list-group properties_list treemenu">
    <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property1</li>
    <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property2</li>
    <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property3</li><li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property4</li><li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property5</li><li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property6</li><li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property7</li><li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property8</li></ul>
```

Comment: Use `line-height`to achieve what you want .. ex: .properties_list .property_item {display: inline-block;font-size: 15px;line-height: 8px;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height: 30px;` in your `.property_item` class to get after it

```css
.properties_list .property_item {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.properties_list {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
.property_item {
    margin-right: 3px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group properties_list treemenu">
  <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property1</li>
  <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property2</li>
  <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property3</li>
  <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property4</li>
  <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property5</li>
  <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property6</li>
  <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property7</li>
  <li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item tree-empty">Property8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: centering with line-height is dangerous when the text doesn't fit on a single line.